# Fetch row where COUNT() in another table and ID doesnt already exist

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables:

```
current_challenges (challenge_id, award_type, award_at_count, expires_in_hours)
```

and

```
user_challenges (user_challenge_id, user_id, challenge_id, awarded)
```

The `current_challenges` table is the type of challenge, and `user_challenges` table is currently 'active' and already 'completed' challenges for the different users. The tables are connected via the `challenge_id`. A completed challenge is one with `awarded` != '0000-00-00 00:00:00', and 'active' one is where `awarded` is a set date time.

What I'd like to do is fetch a random single `challenge_id` that has not already been completed by that specific user, but if there is already 2 of that `award_type` active for the user, then it should not be selected.

So there should only ever be a maximum of 2 challenges 'active with the same award_type for each user.

Example:

current_challenges table:

```
challenge_id    award_type  award_at_count  expires_in_hours
49  1   1   24
50  1   2   24
51  1   3   24
52  2   4   24
53  2   5   24
54  2   6   24
```

user_challenges table:

```
user_challenge_id   user_id     challenge_id    awarded
1   8   49  0000-00-00 00:00:00
2   8   50  0000-00-00 00:00:00
3   8   52  2012-12-06 13:58:27
4   11  53  0000-00-00 00:00:00
5   11  54  0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

For user 8, `challenge_id` 49,50 wouldn't be selected because they are already active. 51 wouldn't because there are already 2 active with `award_type` = '1'. 52 wouldn't because it has already been completed, leaving either 53 or 54 as the returned `challenge_id`.

Sorry for the long post, but wanted to get it as clear as possible. I've had a play for the past day, but got nowhere... `LEFT JOIN` and `HAVING COUNT()` somewhere I'm guessing, but i can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT c.challenge_id
FROM current_challenges AS c
  LEFT JOIN
      ( SELECT cc.award_type                       --- find award types
        FROM current_challenges AS cc              --- with
          JOIN user_challenges AS ac            
            ON ac.challenge_id = cc.challenge_id   --- challenges
        WHERE ac.user_id = 8                       --- for this user
          AND ac.awarded = '0000-00-00'            --- that are active
        GROUP BY cc.award_type
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2                       --- and 2 or more
      ) AS ac
      ON ac.award_type = c.award_type
WHERE ac.award_type IS NULL                        --- and exclude them

  AND c.challenge_id NOT IN                        --- then exclude
      ( SELECT challenge_id                        --- any other challenges
        FROM user_challenges AS uc
        WHERE uc.user_id = 8                       --- for this user
      )
ORDER BY RAND()                                    --- order the result randomly
    LIMIT 1 ;                                      --- and choose one
```